# PDFView scroll line

Tags: pdf-tools

I'm using `<space>` to scroll down in a pdf document that does not fit completely in a frame. However, this disrupts the reading flow as I need to find again the correct line that is now repositioned to show the bottom part of the pdf.
I would like to have a scrolling indicator as illustrated in the second screenshot below. Is someone aware if such a feature already exists for emacs?

View before scrolling down:
[image]

Mockup with a scrolling line. Plus points if the line fades after a couple of seconds.
[image]

Update:
There are two work-in-progress patches in pdf-tools that would solve this issue. Unfortunately, they seem to be abandoned.

- [Indicator for previous line position after scrolling](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/275)
- [Scrolling to last section of a page](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/434)